# how to assign a class to a span in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="edit" contenteditable="true">Some text goes here</span>
```

This span is editable so I can write in it in the browser.Now my question is, when I press the enter key while the cursor is inside this span,the class of this span should be changed from edit to add.Because there is  some css for both of these classes. I know it can be done in jquery by using addClass.toggleClass etc. But I need this to be done in pure javascript as I am using it in TinyMCE editor.

So can anyone help me how it can be done in javascript?

Comment: do you have multiple `edit` fields? a couple of answers assume you don't :/ I would say *all of them* are wrong in a way, as they promote tight coupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some id to the tag and then you can modify the `className` field for that DOM object.

```
document.getElementById("mySpan").className = "add";
```

And the HTML

```
<span id="mySpan" class="edit" contenteditable="true">Some text goes here</span>
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me now.I hope the question I have asked is not a stupid one.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelector('span.edit').className = "add"
```

is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

html:

```
<span id="myspan" class="edit" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="changeClass(event)">Some text goes here</span>
```

js:

```
function changeClass(event){
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
document.getElementById("myspan").className="add"
}
}
```